# Rewrite Specific WordPress Uploads Folders with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, upload, url-rewriting

I need to redirect some WordPress uploads folders and leave others alone.  For example, I need to redirect `http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/image.jpg` to `http://www.mysite.com/assets/2009/08/image.jpg`.

I tried this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.mysite.com/assets/2009/08/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/$1
```

I am using `RedirectMatch` for other redirects and they are working so `RedirectMatch` is enabled.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocol and hostnames don't go into the match in the `RedirectMatch` directive. It only matches against the URI (everything after the hostname, e.g. `/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/image.jpg`). Also, since you are redirecting to the same site, you don't need the `http://www.mysite.com` in your target either:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/assets/2009/08/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/2009/08/$1
```

But the question you're asking is:

> I need to redirect http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/image.jpg to http://www.mysite.com/assets/2009/08/image.jpg.

Which would mean you've got the 2 things backwards if you want to go **from** wp-content **to** assets. You'd need to swap them:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/(.*)$ /assets/2009/08/$1
```

Or you can be even more general:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-content/uploads/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ /assets/$1/$2/$3
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly.  Not sure why I had them backwards.  But now I know, and knowing is half the battle!